# Can't install Kodi because of unmet dependencies:

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, kodi

I recently bought an Orange pi lite and installed armbian on it. Almost everything works like a charm! I even managed to install mate desktop environment and it works great. (Note: I only know the basics of Ubuntu but I am trying to get better and better through practice, aka copy-pasting code)

**The Problem**

I want to install Kodi on the Orange Pi. I have tried to install the latest version as well as the old version(after purging whatever there is left from the latest) via terminal with the following commands:

(for the latest version: )

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kodi
```

(and for the old version: )

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y -r ppa:team-xbmc/kodi-old
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install kodi
```

I have tried some other stuff as well but the result is always the same. When I run the command

`sudo apt-get install kodi`,

this follows :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (>= 2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial) but 15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libshairplay0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libcec4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get -f install` too but still, the result remains the same! I can't figure out what to do or what is really the problem.

Other people with the same exact board have managed to make it work so I know that Kodi can be installed on an orange pi lite running armbian.

For the record the output of `lsb_release -a` is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Please help Ubuntu Gurus!

Thanks.

Comment: Both of the PPAs only have x86 packages for Intel/AMD architecture, and none for ARM. Remove the PPAs with `ppa-purge`, and then try installing from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @mikewhatever It worked great! Lol, too much fuss for nothing!! Thank you very much!!! :)